# Forwarding web traffic from DMZ web server to non-DMZ web server

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, windows, traffic, forwarding

Kind of an odd situation.  I have a web server in a DMZ in one building, and another web server in a different building -- not available to be put in the DMZ.  I was wondering if it's possible to have the DMZ web server forward traffic for a subdomain to the non-DMZ web server.  The DMZ web server is running Windows Server 2003/IIS 6.0, while the non-DMZ web server is running Windows Server 2008 R2/IIS 7.0.  Both servers can see each other, though they are not on the same subnet.

Comment: Why have a DMZ if you're just going to let external web traffic straight through to your protected non-DMZ network?

Comment: The DMZ is run by another department in another building.  My department shares an internet connection with that department via a wireless link.  I would just create my own DMZ had I my own dedicated connection.  So it's either put my web server out of reach in another building, or forward traffic back to my own. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the DMZ box to reverse proxy the content on the non-DMZ machine.
Not sure if/how you can do this in IIS but Apache HTTPd would easily do it.

Comment: Looks like it can be done with IIS/Tomcat Connector and isapi_redirect.  Lets hope it's as painless as it looks...

Answer (score 0):

If both machines can readily see each, one approach may be to serve the contents of the non-DMZ server via a file share from it through the DMZ server.